# CSS extend parent container in dependency of its floating children

Tags: css, html

I have a container whose id is `#parent`, I dynamically add several images of class `.child`, fixed width and height can be assumed for `.child` elements.

I want all `.child` to float next to each other to build a horizontal list. How do I get `#parent` resizing automatically to the total width of all `.child` ?

Thanks a lot!

PS: I need a pure CSS solution..

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u8GPN/1/

Solution can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/u8GPN/28/

Comment: To what limits you want the width of parent to get to?

Comment: in your fiddle you have set width 320px for #view, what after #parent exceed 320px?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your parent `inline-block` and add `white-space: nowrap;` to it:

```
#parent {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u8GPN/22/

To test dynamically adding new blocks http://jsfiddle.net/u8GPN/23/

Comment: I am simulating page overflow with #view in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u8GPN/27/

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can also give `position: absolute` to the `#parent` div to solve the problem for cross-browser support. (or go with `white-space: nowrap` as shown in @dfsq's post)

```
#parent {
     display : block; /* (or) inline-block */
     overflow : hidden;
     border: 1px dashed blue;
     position:absolute; /* Doesn't extend the width more than the page's width */
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u8GPN/25/)

As you stated that the `.child` elements have fixed width and height, You need to give  `#view` height explicitly equal to the `.child` elements height, to occupy the space in layout.